# "HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable" on port sharing with WebListener on Service Fabric

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I want to share http/80 port for two different web application(webpi/website) inside service fabric cluster, the application must have 2 different host name:

`mywebapi.com` and `mywebsite.com`

if i run the apps out of fabric(console app) all works fine:

The first console app

```
 var _webHost = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostBuilder()
    .UseWebListener().UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
    .UseStartup<Startup>().UseUrls("http://myWebApi.com/").Build();
```

The second console app:

```
 var _webHost = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostBuilder()
    .UseWebListener().UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                                               .UseStartup<Startup>()
                                               .UseUrls(
                                                "http://myWebSite.com/"
                                               )
                                               .Build();
```

but if i run apps inside a local fabric i get:

`HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable.`

I've setup correct `ACL` with `netsh` and `SetupEntryPoint(no Access Denied on open)`.

On microsoft `http.sys` guide explicit host is allowed.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you remove any HTTP Endpoint configurations for port 80 in your ServiceManifest.xml, otherwise Service Fabric will override your domain-specific ACLs. See here for info: [host multiple public sites on service fabric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38700563/host-multiple-public-sites-on-service-fabric)

Comment: Can you confirm that i have to add a new firewall rule also?
Seems that fabric create urlacl and a firewall rule for endoint port.
If i don't create firewall rule on local machine(login on machine cluster and navigate with browser) site is up and reachable, but out of cluster the port 80 is closed maybe because probe on that port fail.
Commands:
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="FabricWebSite 80" dir=in action=allow protocol=TCP localport=80
netsh http add urlacl url=http://myWebApi.com:80/ user="NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE"

Answer (score 0):

Why not just publish both to a non 80 port and use the default load balancer to remap it ?

Comment: Have you got some documentation on it?I read default load balancer doesn't "route by hostname"

Comment: Cant help much just starting ourselves in the Azure screen it has a url which is remapped  , it may  be tied to the default domain .  IN the longer term we intend to use the .Core  gateway which has a lot of routing which can be customized.