# How to host multiple HTTPS enabled sites with unique SSL-certificates on single Service Fabric cluster

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-service-fabric

I have Service Fabric cluster on Azure. I would like to use this cluster to host multiple ASP.NET Core based sites. All sites have to be accessible on Internet via HTTPS (on port 443). Also each site operates on different domain thus having unique SSL certificates. Some sites even have wild card certificates.

I've learned that using WebListener is the recommended way to host ASP.NET Core based sites on Service Fabric. As far as I know WebListener should support binding multiple sites to the same port by using the request HTTP headers to recognize the requested site. This is cool, but I have not found information on how to bind the SSL certificates to the sites (hostname). Is it even possible?

If it's not possible to bind certificates to the specific site when using WebListener, I don't know of any practical way of achieving this.

Does somebody have an idea how to solve this issue in a manner that is practical for adding new sites to the cluster with minimal work and expense (performance or infrastructure cost)?

I guess one way would be to use unique port for each site and then doing work on Azure Load Balancer and/or Application Gateway. This could get a bit complicated to manage and even costly (public IPs and application gateway aren't exactly free).

Answer (score 1):

So having just spun up a new ASP.Net Core WebSite I can see that the program.cs file contains a specific ICommunicationListner implementation for .Net Core. I would modify the following method on that listener to allow you to specify an app root, similar to what the default Owin communication listener does for WebAPI. This would allow you to bind multiple sites to the single port.

```
Task ICommunicationListener.OpenAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
            {
                var endpoint = FabricRuntime.GetActivationContext().GetEndpoint(_endpointName);

                string serverUrl = $"{endpoint.Protocol}://{FabricRuntime.GetNodeContext().IPAddressOrFQDN}:{endpoint.Port}";

                _webHost = new WebHostBuilder().UseWebListener()
                                               .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                                               .UseStartup()
                                               .UseUrls(serverUrl)
                                               .Build();

                _webHost.Start();

                return Task.FromResult(serverUrl);
            }
```

The change may look like this:

```
string serverUrl = $"{endpoint.Protocol}://+{endpoint.Port}/{this.appRoot}";
```

Then within the service manifest file tweak the endpoint configuration to run on https and 443

```
 <Endpoints>
      <Endpoint Protocol="https" Name="ServiceEndpoint" Type="Input" Port="443" />
</Endpoints>
```

And then in the Service Fabric application manifest add in the certificate (which should already be deployed to the VMS) using the thumbprint to identify which certificate to use, like so.

Then still within the application manifest add in a policy to bind that certificate to the endpoint for your service

```
<ServiceManifestImport>
    <ServiceManifestRef ServiceManifestName="Web1Pkg" ServiceManifestVersion="1.0.0" />
    <ConfigOverrides />
    <Policies>
      <EndpointBindingPolicy EndpointRef="ServiceEndpoint" CertificateRef="Cert1" />
    </Policies>
  </ServiceManifestImport>
```

EDIT:
Fixed typo in service url (approot was in wrong location) and replaced default kestrel extension with weblistener.

EDIT 2:
Updated the service url to use wild card due to how binding works with the Web Listener

Comment: Sorry, but this doesn't do what I asked for. I want to have multiple sites, each binded to different domain, not on different path. Also each site needs separate SSL certificate. Also Kestrel isn't intended for internet facing sites, so I cannot use it.

Comment: Also i don't think this would actually even work as kestrel doesn't support port sharing. One shouldn't be able to bind multiple kestrel servers to single port.

Comment: Your updated answer shouldn't cut it either. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38700563/host-multiple-public-sites-on-service-fabric  The main problem is the multiple SSL certificates on same port and I don't think it has anything to do with service fabric.

Comment: I agree with your comment, the initial edit was purely due a oversight of copying and pasting along with a typo in the initial serviceUrl and wasn't intended for any specific purpose. I have also updated now to use a wild card in the service url due how WebListener handles its binding. That being said, as you mentioned this currently only works for multiple sites on the same port with the same certificate. I will continue to investigate and let you know if I find a clean way to approach this. If not I will remove the answer.

Answer (score 0):

As you already said, one way to do it (we do it with 3 domains), is to have X public IP addresses. Each of those is forwarded to an internal port (different for each) that has a website listing on that port (or one app listening on multiple ports). Then you can assign SSL and such to each of those.

`PublicIP1:443 -> Port 447 -> Webapp listening on port 447
PublicIP2:443 -> Port 448 -> Webapp listening on port 448
PublicIP3:443 -> Port 449 -> Webapp listening on port 449`

All in all, using ServiceFabric just as a hosting solution for websites is probably not something I would do. If I had to host multiple (read many) websites, I'd do that on Azure App Service. If I then had need for processing/persistence of data on scale, I'd look at maybe using SF for that. But that doesn't mean that the websites has to run on SF.

Comment: I tried to implement this yesterday and indeed it works and is probably ok to manage if one doesn't have really high amount of sites. But indeed using app service is easier and probably better fit at this point. It is unfortunate as it would be great if I could efficiently and easily reuse the service fabric infrastructure for general site hosting.

Comment: Another way of solving it would be to put something like HAProxy in front to deal with SSL termination and reverse proxying requests to the correct WebApp running in SF.
You would then probably have to have the WebApps register with HAProxy when they start, and de-register when they shut down.